# Using "among others" for a list of workplaces

Tags: phrase-usage, lists

How is "among others" used properly? Is it used properly in this sentence?:

> I have **among others** worked in a bakery and a restaurant

I've looked at the [definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/among-others) of it. It says:

> used to indicate that there are several **more people like the one** or ones **mentioned, but that you do not intend to mention them all**

Does that mean I can't use it when it's not people I am talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The usage of "among others"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37772/the-usage-of-among-others)

Comment: @Andrew, this is not a duplicate of the question you quoted. It asks whether you can use "among others" about things, which the answers to the question you quoted do not answer satisfactorily.

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm not going to quibble since this really belongs more on *meta*, but I'm confused because, if you look at the top answer for that question, it gives two examples, both of which are about people.  So it felt like I couldn't add anything meaningful to *this* question which wouldn't simply reiterate the answer to *that* question.

Comment: Yes @Andrew, the top answer does give two examples about people, because the other question **doesn't** ask about things. This question **specifically** asks about things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression **among others** is mainly used about people, but it can also be used about things. Here are some examples:

> The American longshore workers held work stoppages in relationship to South African apartheid, the war in Vietnam, and the war in Iraq, among others. [In the interest of others](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=ospX9gsJsUYC&pg=PA79&dq=%22among%20others%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb9au95OTPAhUiK8AKHQUjAy04MhDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22among%20others%22&f=false)
>
> The same dish is found in several Latin American countries (Costa Rica, Mexico,and Cuba among others). [Building bridges among the BRICs](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=rMAaBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&dq=%22among%20others%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiphcKo5eTPAhVKD8AKHZjxDQU4UBDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=%22among%20others%22&f=false)
>
> The risk associated with RYGB may include incisional hernias, nutrient deficiencies, marginal ulcers, pulmonary embolism, small bowel obstruction and wound infection, among others. [Acceptability of weight loss treatments...](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=8Pz0foimYikC&pg=PA7&dq=%22among%20others%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiphcKo5eTPAhVKD8AKHZjxDQU4UBDoAQg-MAc#v=onepage&q=%22among%20others%22&f=false)

The key to its successful use for things is to include it at the end of a list that includes at least three items. To make your sentence work, you would have to say:

> I have worked in a bakery, a cafe, and a restaurant, among others.

Comment: I don't know if the list really requires three items to work, but the rest of this is correct and helpful advice.

Comment: What would be an alternative to use besides among other?

Comment: @surfmuggle, you could use et cetera, which means **and the rest**. The meaning isn't quite the same though.

Comment: @JavaLatte thanks for your reply, would et cetera fit in [this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915388/):`The site in question has these header fields among others`  - meaning that these are only a part of the fields (an extract? a sub quantity / sub portion?). Does sub portion or sub quantity fit better for discrete / heterogeneous things?

Comment: @surfmuggle: I don't think that et cetera works in that example. The specified header fields have a particular importance to the point being made, and the other fields do not. et cetera would be OK if you were providing a random selection of header fields, and the et cetera fields have the same relevance as the ones that you refer explicitly to.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. It's a perfectly good usage.  There are lots of examples of "among others" used as you suggest found in the [BYU Corpus.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/) Here's one:

> Mr. Easterbrook -- who writes for The New Republic, The Atlantic Monthly, ESPN.com., and this magazine, among others discusses...etc

But note that the sentence makes clear the category of thing (publications)

So I'd suggest adding a phrase that makes that clear, for example,

> David works at several retail stores, among them, a bakery.

As an aside, the word "among" typically denotes more than two things, so if David only works at a bakery and one other place, I would revise.